# How can I get a line height from font size within browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, getclientrect

`Range.getClientRects()` method returns a list of `ClientRect` occupied by `range` and this works well when the range is within normal span which has text.

```
<div class="line">
  <span class="run">Hello!</span><span class="run"></span>
</div>
```

But it fails to get `ClientRect` when span is empty. (like in the second span)

I've tried the followings, however, the results were not satisfactory.

- Set span's display property to `inline-block`
- Insert `'\ufeff'` into span. In this case, I can get `ClientRect` but this will mess up the other parts of codes.

If I can compute line height from the `font-size`, it would be best. Is there any way to get the line height of empty span in px?

**NOTE:** I'm not trying to get `line-height` css property. In this case, the `line-height` would be `normal`.

Comment: What other parts of your codes get messed up?  Can you just undo your changes immediately after you get the value?

Comment: You can't compute line-height from font-size -- it's both browser dependent and font-family dependent.  Sorry for the super unhelpful "answer" :)

Comment: I expected formula that compute line height from font size. Now I understand that it depends on both browser and font-family, which means it can't be calculated from a simple formula. Thank you for your comment and interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just put any character into this `<span>`. In this case, I put a `U+FEFF` character.

   ```
   var elem = $('span')[0];
   elem.textContent = '\ufeff';
   ```
2. Get a rectangle.

   ```
   var rect = elem.getClientRect();
   ...
   ```
3. Restore the `<span>` to be empty.

   ```
   elem.textContent = '';
   ```

Comment: Works perfectly. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: ugh.  exactly what I commented.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could traverse the DOM tree above the span to find the nearest element with a numerical line-height definition.  In my test case this seems to work on percentage line-heights too -- it gets the computed line-height not the percentage. I'm not sure about the cross-browser support on that though.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/colllin/DHLWW/

Code:

```
var lineHeight = -1;
var $span = $('span');
var tree = $span.get().concat( $span.parents().get() );
$(tree).each(function(index, element) {
    if (lineHeight < 0) {
        lineHeight = parseFloat($(element).css('line-height')) || -1;
    }
});
$(document.body).append('<br>line-height of span: '+lineHeight);
```

Comment: The idea of getting the height of parent element is good. However, it doesn't solve the problem completely. Consider that the div contains two spans which have different font size, respectively. –